# GtkSharp - Window.Opacity is ignored while showing the window

Tags: c#, gtk#, gtk2

Using GtkSharp with .Net Core project on Windows platform:

`<PackageReference Include="GtkSharp" Version="3.24.24.4" />`

I am trying to simulate fade-in simple animation. In Window constructor `Opacity` is set to 0.1 and then a timer is set to keep increasing it up to 1.
Now, despite the value of the property `Window.Opacity` is correct (first time call of timout handler it is 0.1, as set in constructor) the window at the begining is always show with full opacity (like the value set in constructor was ignored).

**Consecutive updates of this property from the timer handler works properly** (Opacity value is updated and actual opacity of the window on the screen follows). It just ignores Opacity the very first show if the window.

I tried seting Opacity from Shown handler, before Window.Show(), after Window.Show() and few others - it is always visible after construction and showing with full opacity despite the value of `Opacity` property is set to 0.1 (or any othe value >= 0). It ignores it the same way when set in .glade file.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
        {
    
            public MainWindow() : this(new Builder("MainWindow.glade")) { }
            private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetObject("MainWindow").Handle)
            {
    
                builder.Autoconnect(this);          
    
                Opacity = 0.1;
                GLib.Timeout.Add(2000, new GLib.TimeoutHandler(fadein_timeout));
            }
    
            bool fadein_timeout()
            {
                this.Opacity += 0.1;   // first time here, value of Opacity is 0.1 (as expected), but windows is shown with 100% opacity (unexpected)
                if (Opacity >= 1.0)
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
}
```

Any idea how to make it work? Ofc, I want to avoid workaround with 'quick' timeout to quicly hide it at the begining, to avoid flickering.

Comment: What you are dealing with is Window's show-window-animation. Windows does a quick fade-in before the window is fully realized. This is an OS-level thing. You will probably have to change it from a TopLevel window to something else (Tool window? Dialog?) in order for it to stop doing that. Whatever you end up doing may be kludgy.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty decent solution (works both on Windows and Linux platforms) is to animate `Widget.Opacity` of the main container (e.g. `GtkBox` ) control inside the main window (via `Widget` interface).

Opacity works as expected in all cases for a control widget with GtkSharp. For example:

```
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [UI] Widget _mainBox = null; // this is the main container control, e.g. GtkBox

        public MainWindow() : this(new Builder("MainWindow.glade")) { }
        private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetObject("MainWindow").Handle)
        {

            builder.Autoconnect(this);          

            _mainBox.Opacity = 0.1;
            GLib.Timeout.Add(50, new GLib.TimeoutHandler(fadein_timeout));
        }

        bool fadein_timeout()
        {
            _mainBox.Opacity += 0.01;   
            if (_mainBox.Opacity >= 1.0)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
  }
```

Tested on Windows 10 and pure X11 (Linux Arm).